# Implement Chaotic System In The Most Stable Way

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Disclaimer: This is half a crosspost from [Computer Graphics SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/zebra-like-patterns-generated-by-linear-pde), someone recommended to put it here.

I wrote a program generating image frames based on a naive implementation of the PDE $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}=A\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+B\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$ with application of Gassian blur in between.  [Here](https://codepen.io/fweth/full/VwbNeyG) is a slight variation taking polar coordinates instead of $x$ and $y$, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwEhv.jpg) are some images generated by the system.  The check pattern is the initialization, it circles around while the algorithm does its thing.

It shows that the patterns emerge slightly different in each round.  I suspect this is because the system is rather chaotic, but I still wonder if there are some techniques I could apply to make the output more deterministic.  One idea was to move away from pixels as discretization and instead use a randomized but fixed Delaunay triangulation of the plane.  Would that be of any benefit?  Any other strategies?

Comment: the fact that the equation is linear suggests that it can be solved via a Fourier transform. Maybe you can find an exact solution.

Comment: That's interesting, will look into it!

Comment: @fweth What exactly are you plotting?

Comment: @PierreCarre it's more of a visual project, so there is a little bit going on in the plots to make them look 'interesting'.  Every color vector longer than one gets normalized, to avoid getting out of RGB color cube.  Also I have a border which is fixed at zero.  Then I have this thing circling around and resetting pixels to the check pattern.  Apart from that, in each frame I sample from the last frame but with the position distorted by Gaussian distributed noise.  From that layer, I compute the next frame using the equation described above.